How can I generate an entity–relationship (ER) diagram of a SQL data warehouse (dedicated SQL pool) database using Visio?
How can I generate an entity–relationship (ER) diagram of a  SQL data warehouse (dedicated SQL pool) database using Visio?
Trying to create dedicated SQL pool (Synapse Analytics) db schemas ER diagrams using Visio. Need help to find the correct ODBC for this.

The below are steps to create a Database Model (also known as Entity Relationship diagram) in Visio.
In Visio, using the Database Model Diagram template, you can either create a new database model or analyze an existing database to create a corresponding model.
Note: The Database Model diagram is only available in certain versions of Visio. See Can't find the database modeling features? for more information.
Step 1: Start a database-model diagram
If you do not have an existing database to work from, you can begin with an empty Database Model and manually create your tables and relationships.

Select File > New.
In the Search box, enter database model and press Enter.
In the search results, double-click Database Model Diagram Select either Metric Units or US Units, and then select Create.



The Reverse Engineer Wizard usually opens automatically. Select Cancel to close the wizard.
On the Database tab, in the Manage group, select Display Options.
In the Database Document Options dialog box, select the symbol set that you want to use, And other table and relationship options, and then select OK. Click the Help button in the dialog box to get more information about the various options.

Step 2: Refine the structure of the diagram
Once you have created a database model diagram, the next step is to refine it.
This involves adding and customizing the three primary components of a model:

Entities (or tables),

Columns (which provide details about a table),

Relationships (the connections between tables), which can be one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many.


Step 3: Add features for searching and updating data
To further enhance your diagram, such as adding indexes, check clauses, and triggers, choose a section below for instructions on how to add these refinements.
Know more about Create a Database Model (also known as Entity Relationship diagram) in Visio
